# Ruby "each" method

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

Why does the following method return not lengths of strings, but strings?

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  lengths = []
  input_array.each do |string|
    lengths << string.length
  end
end

>> array = %w{ lol testtest l}
=> ["lol", "testtest", "l"]
>> length_finder(array)
=> ["lol", "testtest", "l"]
```

What I'm expecting to see:

```
>> length_finder(array)
=> [3, 8, 1]
```

This is from the exercise on [rubymonk.com](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/5-string-length-finder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  lengths = []
  input_array.each do |string|
    lengths << string.length
  end
  return lengths
end
```

You need to write 'return length' because Ruby method returns last evaluated expression.

map method returns edited array. Below code is more simple.

```
def length_finder(input_array)
  input_array.map {|item| item.length}
end
```

Comment: Note you can write `input_array.map {|item| item.length}` as `input_array.map(&:length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `each` returns the receiver `input_array`, which is an array of strings.

Comment: But `lengths` has nothing to do with what `each` returns.I still don't understand why the line `lengths << string.length` doesn't do what I expect it to do

Comment: It is doing what you are expecting to do. Before the last 'end' add lengths and that variable will be returned.

Comment: Exactly. `lengths` has nothing to do with what `each` returns. What did you expect `lengths << string.length` to do?

Answer (score 0):

The indentation on the line starting with "input_array.each" indicates that the "end" statement ties together with the .each method.  Because it was defined in the less-indented scope, lengths is still populated by the most indented line,

```
lengths << string.length
```

However, the Ruby parser considers the last line of the function to be the return statement: "end" refers to the .each method, which returns an array of strings.

Even though the lengths[] array is exactly as you want it now, The **last** line needs to refer directly to the variable you are returning.  "end" refers to the line **above** the object you want to return.